# how to subset a list on basis of multiple conditions in R?

Tags: r, subset

I have a list containing value, level, id, colorvalue, actual value, A,B, change, name and parent. I want to subset  "value" greater than 1000 at "level" = 2 only. It should subset only for level 2, there are 2,3,4 levels in list. Actually, data is in format of data tree having hierarchies, the levels are like layers starting from 2,3,4. So, what I actually want to achieve is that for level 2 only the value should be filtered on basis of conditions and other levels should remain same. So finally I should have all data from level 2,3,4 and level 2 having values > 1000 only.

list :

```
    [[1]]
[[1]]$value
[1] 19.48275

[[1]]$level
[1] 4

[[1]]$id
[1] "10"

[[1]]$colorValue
[1] 4244.56

[[1]]$actualvalue
[1] 4244.56

[[1]]$A
[1] 21786.25

[[1]]$B
[1] 17541.69

[[1]]$change
[1] 19.48275

[[1]]$name
[1] "HFSS"

[[1]]$parent
[1] "7"


[[2]]
[[2]]$value
[1] Inf

[[2]]$level
[1] 4

[[2]]$id
[1] "100"
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the `list` and filter the `list` elements based on the condition in the OP's post.

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[(x[["value"]] > 1000 & x[["level"]]==2)|x[["level"]]!=2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is filtering and giving me list for "value" only at  level 2. I am not able to get other elements(actualvalue, A,B...) and also i want to have data from other "levels"(3,4).

Comment: @user6559913  It is based on your description `I want to subset "value" greater than 1000 at "level" = 2 only`.  Your comment about `I want to have data from other levels "levels"(3,4)` is cofusing as well based on your description

Comment: @user6559913  Yes, if you show in your post the expected output and a reproducible example with dput.  In your example, there is only level 4 and I don't know what exactly you wanted

Comment: Actually, data is in format of data tree having hierarchies, the levels are like layers starting from 2,3,4. So, what I actually want to achieve is that for level 2 only the value should be filtered on basis of conditions  and other levels should remain same.  So finally I should have all data from level 2,3,4 and level 2 having values > 1000 only.

Comment: @user6559913  `finally I should have all data from level 2,3,4 and level 2 having values > 1000 only.`  it may be easier to describe for you as data is in front of you, but for me it is not entirely clear.  I am confused with `level2 having values > 1000 only`  did you meant that for those list elements having `level2` you want to subset only those with values > 1000 while the other level list should remain?